# SSRS multi page report

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have to generate a SSRS multiple page report. I have a list "data" and have to do following.
data contains name, salary and address

```
data[0] = abc,1000,def
data[1] = pqr,2000,xyz

for(int i =0; i<data.Count; i++)
{    
   //when the value of i is 0 information must be printed on 1st page.
   //when value of is 1 information must be printed on 2nd page and so on...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you are looking for is a `for` loop construct like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length;)
{
    int page = ++i;

    // Write the data on the page in the int variable above.
}
```

Comment: I am new to SSRS so I dont know anything about it. Can you please tell me more how can I go to next page. I have ReportViewer1 and I am binding my report as follows                          ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSetCostSheet", data);
            reportCostSheet.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

Comment: @boy_shiv Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904994/can-the-net-reportviewer-control-be-fully-operated-by-code-only-ie-minus-the